# Change the default base url for axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have configured my axios like this

```
const axiosConfig = {
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api',
  timeout: 30000,
};

Vue.prototype.$axios = axios.create(axiosConfig)
```

Inside my component, I make a call as

```
this.$axios.get('items').then()..
```

Now the above works but I would like to change the `baseURL` without affecting the global base URL so that in my component I can simply use it without API endpoint so

I've tried

```
this.$axios.baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
this.$axios.get().. //this is still in api endpoint
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: you can change the base url of an axios instance by setting: `this.$axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://localhost:8000"`

Comment: for other visitors, to temporary changing baseURL, you can pass the absolute url to the desired method:
`this.$axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/items')`

Comment: `axios.get('/items', { baseUrl: 'https://another-endpoint' }` or another example `axios.post('/items', payload, { baseUrl: 'https://another-endpoint' })` is another option. See https://github.com/axios/axios#config-order-of-precedence for an order of config precedence.

Comment: then what is the use of creating an instance with baseURL? `axios.create(axiosConfig)`

Comment: @Naren There's no one answer to that. In my case, I am transitioning from a v1 API to a v2 api. I can set the baseURL to `/api/v2` and then add the override in each method to `/api/v1`. As I build up v2 replacements in my endpoint I can one by one remove the overrides until it's all transitioned over to v2.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Instead of

```
this.$axios.get('items')
```

use

```
this.$axios({ url: 'items', baseURL: 'http://new-url.com' })
```

If you don't pass `method: 'XXX'` then by default, it will send via `get` method.

**Request Config:** https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

Comment: for temporary changing baseURL, you can pass absolute url to the desired method:
`this.$axios.get('http://new-url.com/items')`. No need to pass all the params as an object to `this.$axios`

Comment: While this changes baseURL, it is same for all build modes. + it changes baseUrl only for this single specific axios request. How it is done correctly and in VUE way, check my answer.

Answer (score 80):

Putting my two cents here. I wanted to do the same without hardcoding the URL for my specific request. So i came up with this solution.

To append `'api'` to my baseURL, I have my default baseURL set as,

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = '/api/';
```

Then in my specific request, after explicitly setting the method and url, i set the baseURL to `'/'`

```
axios({
    method:'post',
    url:'logout',
    baseURL: '/',
   })
   .then(response => {
      window.location.reload();
   })
   .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
   });
```

Comment: So if you don't set the `baseUrl` in your method, it won't work with relative paths? I can get `baseUrl` to work if I type in a explicit url like `http://server01.domain.com` but I have to set up the app on multiple servers, each independent.

Comment: @Jack I'm dealing with your same scenario, did you find an elegant fix to it?

Comment: @MatiasSalimbene I set global to `/MyApp/api` without setting it in the method.  Then set the router to `/MyApp`

Answer (score 15):

1. Create **.env.development**, **.env.production** files if not exists and add there your API endpoint, for example: `VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT ='http://localtest.me:8000'`
2. In main.js file, add this line after imports: `axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT`

And that's it. Axios default base Url is replaced with build mode specific API endpoint.
If you need specific baseURL for specific request, do it like this:

```
this.$axios({ url: 'items', baseURL: 'http://new-url.com' })
```

Answer (score 12):

If someone else still needs help with this:

You can change the Axios base URL directly where you want to use it

```
anotherAxiosRequest(){
 axios.defaults.baseURL = http://wwww.example.com
 axios({
   url:'/cats' //=>  http://wwww.example.com/cats
 })
}
```

and it will change the base URL

note that this will not change the base URL defined in main.js

Comment: This will change configuration for all upcoming requests. You should better pass it as a config for this request only: ```axios({ url:'/cats', baseURL: 'http://wwww.example.com' })```

Answer (score 2):

From [axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) you have *baseURL* and *url*

`baseURL` will be prepended to `url` when making requests. So you can define `baseURL` as `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and make your requests to `/url`

> ```
>  // `url` is the server URL that will be used for the request
>  url: '/user',
>
>  // `baseURL` will be prepended to `url` unless `url` is absolute.
>  // It can be convenient to set `baseURL` for an instance of axios to pass relative URLs
>  // to methods of that instance.
>  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
> ```

Comment: I've read those Axios docs, but weirdly my `baseURL` never gets prepended. Everything works fine if I just pretend that the `baseURL` feature doesn't exist and change my `url` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this
(for nuxt and vue)

```js
this.$axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://example.com/example'
```

this worked for me for  custom   baseURL  for one request

```js
async getDataFromServer({ commit }, payload) {
    commit('setLoadingStatus', true)
    try {
      const page = payload.page || 1
      const sort = payload.sort || 'published_at'

      this.$axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://example.com/example'
     
      const { data } = await this.$axios.get(`/example`)

      commit('setItOnState', data)
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e)
    } finally {
      commit('setLoadingStatus', false)
    }
  },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You could put in something like...

```
axios.get("https://your-url", {baseURL:"")
```

This will override the baseURL in the axios interceptor for this specific axios request.