# Vue.js interceptors not working and nothing return

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have problem with axios interceptors. I try set header for jwt using interceptors but nothing work so I changed my code and added only console.log to this code. When I open console in Chrome nothing is displayed. Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

```
import axios from 'axios'
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080'
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  params: {}
})

instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    console.log('test');

     return config;
 }, function (error) {
     return Promise.reject(error)
 })

 export default instance
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the default base url for axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407564/change-the-default-base-url-for-axios)

Comment: I don't think so, I have problem with interceptors which not return console.log('test'); I haven't idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look into an old project that I used `interceptors`. There I called it directly on the `axios` object.

Perhaps something like the code bellow will work.

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080';

axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    
    console.log('config', config);

    return config;
}, function (error) {

    return Promise.reject(error)
});

export default instance;
```