# My nextJS running on 3000 is not fetching my backend server running on 5000

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js

I am trying to fetch a json file from my backend folder. I have deployed nodeJs server in port 5000.
this is my server-side code.

```
const express = require('express');
const chats = require('./data/data.js');
const cors = require('cors')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://127.0.0.1:5000',
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("API running");
});

app.get('/api/chat', (req, res) => {
    res.send(chats);
});

app.get('/api/chat/:id', (req, res) => {
    const sChat = chats.find((c) => c._id === req.params.id);
    res.send(sChat);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listining on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

- I have used cors
- I have also defined proxy in my frontend package .json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "next": "13.5.6",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
}
```

My frontend is made with nextjs and deployed using yarn and below is the code

```
'use client'

import axios from "axios"
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home() {
    const fetchChats = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get('/api/chat');
            console.log(res.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchChats();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <p>Chats</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

My frontend is still fetching ...:3000/api/chat instead of ....:5000/api/chat. I have tried everything from clearing cache to restarting the servers mutiple times.

I think my proxy is giving me the problem as when i run `axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/chat');` it is fetching the data

Please help as chatGPT is just repeating same thing again and again.

Comment: Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: add your `package.json` file and the sever side code to the question.

Comment: Updated the question with both the code

Comment: You need to update the base url setting for axios, not at the nextjs level. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407564/change-the-default-base-url-for-axios

Comment: Will updating the base url of axios create any problem for me later on?

Answer (score 0):

Axios will by default take your localhost:3000 as your domain, if you don't provide the domain of your backend server explictly. Try the below code.

```
 const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/chat');
```

or you can provide the domain of your backend server. The above code will work if you are running the backend server on your local machine.

---

The proper way to implement that using .env file. Create .env.local file and put this code

`REACT_APP_URI = "localhost:5000"`

Now, you can use it like that

`const res = await axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_URI + '/api/chat');`

Comment: I have done this and yeah it works. But defining the full url is not good for the long term as it will cause problem when I try to deploy my website. Any other solutions?

Comment: @Andy use environment variables for different environments